# Plot list as a colorbar to efficiently visualize outliers

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar

I'd like to generate a colorbar for values stored in a list

```
def map_values_to_color(data: List, cmap: str, integer=False):
   
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(data), vmax=max(data), clip=True)
    mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

    if integer:
        color = [[r, g, b] for r, g, b, a in mapper.to_rgba(data, bytes=True)]
    else:
        color = [[r, g, b] for r, g, b, a in mapper.to_rgba(data)]

    colorlist = [(val, color) for val, color in zip(data, color)]

    return colorlist
    
if __name__ == '__main__':


    vals = [100, .80, .10, .79, .70, .60, .75, .78, .65, .90] 

    colorlist = map_values_to_color(data=vals, cmap='bwr_r', integer=True)
```

Any suggestions on how to generate just the colorbar will be really helpful.

EDIT:
Output obtained from the below code:

[image]

EDIT2:
The below answer might be useful for lists without outliers. However, my data has outliers and I am still looking for suggestions/ inputs on how to visualize the data with outliers efficiently using a colorbar i.e some sort of a discrete colorbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they told you, you need a 2-d array to use `imshow`, but you need a 1-row, N-columns array to represent the inherently mono-dimensionality of a list.

Further, we can apply a little bit of cosmetics to the ticks to simplify the plot (I removed the y ticks because you do not really have an y axis) and to make easier to identify the outliers (I specified a denser set of x ticks — beware that for a really long list this must be adapted in some way).

Last but not least, you have a strict definition of outliers and want a colormap describing in detail the *correct* range and evidencing the outliers, with this regard I have adapted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081384/2749397) by [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington), in which we modify the colormap to show contrasting colors for the outliers and specify, at the level of `imshow`, which is the range outside of which we have outliers.

Here it is my script (note the extended slicing syntax that makes a 1-d array a 2-d one, the use of `vmin` and `vmax`, the use of `extend='both' and how we set the contrasting colors for the outliers)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vals = [100, .80, .10, .79, .70, -80, .75, .78, .65, .90]
arr = np.array(vals)[None, :] # arr.shape ⇒ (1, 10)
###   #######################
im = plt.imshow(arr, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='bwr')                
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, extend='both', orientation='horizontal')
cbar.cmap.set_under('yellow') , cbar.cmap.set_over('green')
plt.xticks(range(len(vals))), plt.yticks(())
plt.show
```

The script produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response . But I still see the same problem after adding `plt.colorbar()`. The values that are less than 1 are assigned a single color. I'd like to view the values < 1 with distinct color mapping.